Optimizing turning integer vectors into binary vectors
I have a bunch of 4 million integer vectors that I have to convert to binary. My code is as follows:
def integer_vectors_to_binary(data, bits=16):
    bin_arr = []
    for arr in tqdm(data, desc="Processing", ncols=100):
        binary_array = [list(map(int, format(x, f'0{bits}b'))) for x in arr]
        bin_arr.append(np.array(binary_array).flatten())
    return np.asarray(bin_arr)

Now, the issue is that the process takes too long for my very large input set. Therefore, I was wondering if this code could be optimized. Here's a sample output:
vec_a = np.asarray([12, 15, 14])
print(integer_vectors_to_binary([vec_a]))

The output is:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
Think of vec_a with 254 elements where each element is an integer with values from 0-65535.

Is the call of tqdm really relevant to your question? If your concern is speed, that would be the first thing to drop. If your question is  only about the loop body, then just reduce the code to that part for this question.

tqdm helps me visualise the progress. Else it feels like nothing is happening!

So it isn't relevant to your question...

Also, your example input is a flat array, but your code expects data is an iterable of iterables (arr). So the call integer_vectors_to_binary(vec_a) will run into an error. How do you call your function?

Yes, that was for example purposes. In the original code snippet, it would be [data]

You mean [vec_a]? Can you add the code that calls your function to your question? Can you use a less trivial example input (and corresponding output), where the outer loop has to make more than one iteration?

This is how I generate the output: print(integer_vectors_to_binary(vec_a), and yes, I mean [vec_a]

Can you edit the question (use the link below the question) and add this information? Could you update the example so it is one that will result in more than one outer-loop iteration, and add the corresponding expected output?

Done! I have made the changes to the question

Thanks, but the example is still the trivial one. Can you update?

Do you need to have a list of 0 or 1 or a list of strings like "0000000000000111" is fine?

Is this what you were looking for?

@ken This is the best answer! I only wish I could have marked this as the accepted one. Reduces the conversion time to 2 minutes, which is acceptable!
